# How can we achieve RSA with OAEP Padding in Jmeter?

Tags: encryption, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I need to use this Piece code in Jmeter to get the encryption of Strings.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding", "BC");
```

How can we achieve the same in Jmeter ? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code in one of the [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like:

```
def cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
log.info(cipher.getAlgorithm())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Encryption in Groovy]

Once you get an encrypted string you will be able to store it in [JMeter Variables](http://%09def%20cipher%20=%20javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(%22AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING%22);%20%09log.info(cipher.getAlgorithm())) using `vars` shorthand which stands for JMeterVariables class instance like:

```
vars.put('myEncryptedString', new String(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes()))
```

And refer it as `${myEncryptedString}` where required.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. But i have got error as "javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No such provider: BC" with this code def cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding","BC");
log.info(cipher.getAlgorithm());

Comment: My expectation is that you need to add [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) library to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). JMeter restart will be required to pick the jar up

Comment: Tried That too @Dmitri T. But still throwing the same error :(

Comment: @Dimitri I am trying to run same test. Can you explain in bit detail how to encrypt extracted Jmeter values.? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437538/how-to-rsa-encrypt-session-key-in-jmeter